# String containing _ shorten to first and last character

Tags: string, powershell, substring

I have file Text.txt containing:

sometext1 sometext2 sometext3 sometext4_sometext5_sometext6 sometext7 sometext8 sometext9_sometext10 sometext11

and i need only string containing _ shorten to first and last character, in powershell, to output:

sometext1 sometext2 sometext3 s4_s5_s6 sometext7 sometext8 s9_s0 sometext11

I'm a newbie in Powershell.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
This is a forum where coders voluntarily help other coders with their challenges. ;-) There are some rules and best practices helping you to get the most out of SO. 
First you may take the [Tour] to get an overview and then you may stop by on [ask]. 
To make it easier for others willing to help you to actually help you you should always [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly, avoid [posting images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and provide a [mre].

Comment: please show what you have coded so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit of a lengthy Regex, but I think it does what you need:

(?<=*[^*])[^\s_]+(?=[^\s_]*|[^*]\s)|(?<=\s[^*])[^\s*]+(?=[^\s_]_)

to be used like this:

```
sometext1 sometext2 sometext3 sometext4_sometext5_sometext6 sometext7 sometext8 sometext9_sometext10 sometext11' -replace '(?<=_[^_])[^\s_]+(?=[^\s_]_|[^_]\s)|(?<=\s[^_])[^\s_]+(?=[^\s_]_)
```

Here's the explanation of the Regex:
https://regex101.com/r/aYVoa6/1

Comment: Thank you for your help. Full code is:

# Read the content of the Text.txt file
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Test\Text.txt")

# Define a regular expression pattern to match strings containing underscores
$pattern = '(?<=_[^_])[^\s_]+(?=[^\s_]_|[^_]\s)|(?<=\s[^_])[^\s_]+(?=[^\s_]_)'

# Replace matching strings with shortened versions
$shortenedContent = [regex]::Replace($content, $pattern, { param($match) $match.Groups[1].Value -replace '$' })

# Output the result to file
$shortenedContent  | Out-File "C:\Test\Text output.txt"